# Accesing Identity Profile Management

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I'm stuck with this problem for over 2 hours and can't find the answer anywhere.
I have a project that uses Identity. I have created a register and login **not using Identity scaffolded items** from the beginning.

Next, I added custom fields to user identity using ApplicationUser:IdentityUSer.

Now I want to allow users to manage their profiles. I wanted to use the default Identity Manager and then customize it. I didn't have it though so I added a new scaffolded Identity with only "Identity/Pages/Account/Manage" item. It has created an area.

The problem is that I don't know how to access the Index page inside this area in my _LoginPartial view.

Part of _LoginPartial code:

```
 @if (SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User))
 {
     <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1 justify-content-end text-center">
         <li class="nav-item mr-5 text-center">
             <a //here i want to access Index page class="nav-link btn">Hello, @User.Identity.Name</a>
         </li>

         <li class="nav-item">
             <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Logout">Logout</a>
         </li>
     </ul>
 }
 else
 {

 }
```

[My project structure:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4wO4V.png)

Is this a good way to manage user profile though?

Answer (score 0):

To have your first `<a>` tag link to your new Account | Manage page, you can include the `asp-area`, `asp-controller` and `asp-action` attributes. (similar to what you already have on your second `<a>` tag).

Try changing the line to this:

```
<a asp-area="Identity" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Manage" class="nav-link btn">Hello, @User.Identity.Name</a>
```